# OpenCart 2.3 - New Theme, where CSS files shall be applied?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am developing a new custom theme for OpenCart 2.3 and following book tutorial.

I am reading header.tpl in OpenCart 2.3 and I see these lines of code:

```
<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $style['href']; ?>" type="text/css" rel="<?php echo $style['rel']; ?>" media="<?php echo $style['media']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Which obviously is loading additional CSS files.
If I have a couple of CSS files to be applied in this custom theme, where should those files be specified?
I understand that I can use:

```
<link href="...css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

but, is there any other way or place to add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the header controller, add:

```
$this->document->addStyle('your-stylesheet.css');
```

your-stylesheet.css should be located here:

```
/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/your-stylesheet.css
```

Comment: Thanks, where "your-stylesheet.css" file shall be located?